# Aggregate date time to summarize time spent at certain 'repeating' conditions

Tags: r, date, datetime, dplyr, summary

Good day,

This is a continuation question to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55268381/aggregate-date-time-to-summarize-time-spent-at-certain-conditions)

Here are some dummy data:

```
Date <- as.POSIXct(c('2018-03-20 11:52:25', '2018-03-22 12:01:44', '2018-03-20 12:05:25', '2018-03-20 12:10:40', '2018-03-20 12:12:51 ', '2018-03-21 2:01:23', '2018-03-21 2:45:01', '2018-03-21 3:30:00', '2018-03-21 3:45:00', '2018-03-21 5:00:00', '2018-03-21 5:45:00')) 
Sites<-c(4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 7, 7, 4, 4, 6, 6)
Individual<-c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A","A")

data<-data.frame(Individual, Date, Sites)

   Individual                Date Sites
           A 2018-03-20 11:52:25     4
           A 2018-03-22 12:01:44     4
           A 2018-03-20 12:05:25     4
           A 2018-03-20 12:10:40     6
           A 2018-03-20 12:12:51     6
           A 2018-03-21 02:01:23     7
           A 2018-03-21 02:45:01     7
           A 2018-03-21 03:30:00     4
           A 2018-03-21 03:45:00     4
           A 2018-03-21 05:00:00     6
           A 2018-03-21 05:45:00     6
```

Basically, I would like R to tell me how much time is spent at each site. The data above, have repeating instances at sites and I would like R to tease out the repetitions and add the time differences for each.

I have tried the following code:

```
data.summary<-data %>%
  group_by(Individual, Sites) %>%
  summarise(time_spent = max(Date)-min(Date))
```

But this will take a time difference from just the minimum date at that site and the maximum date at the site, not accounting for instances of repetition, or times that the individual is at other sites.

Digging further into the dummy data, the summarize code says that individual A spent 2 days at site 4. However that individual left site 4 and reentered the site at a later date and should have a total time at site 4 of 28 minutes. How can I get R to reflect repetitive entries for that site?

```
Date1<-as.POSIXct("2018-03-20 11:52:25") # First instance at site 4
Date2<-as.POSIXct("2018-03-20 12:05:25") # Last time A spent at site 4 before leaving
difftime(Date2, Date1, units="mins")
# time diff = 13 minutes

# Second instance at site 4
Date3<-as.POSIXct("2018-03-21 03:30:00") # Second instance at site 4
Date4<-as.POSIXct("2018-03-21 03:45:00") # Last time A spent at site 4
difftime(Date4, Date3, units="mins")
# time diff= 15 mins
```

Thanks!

EDIT: I'm finding an issue with dplyr summarise, where extra time is being added. Here are dummy data:

```
Dates<-as.POSIXct(c("2018-04-09 16:59:03",
"2018-04-09 18:27:23",
"2018-04-09 17:01:20",
"2018-04-09 17:41:17"))
Individual<-c("A","A","A","A")
Site<-c("40","40","40", "40")

data<-data.frame(Dates, Individual, Site)
```

I want to summarize the time spent at site 40, with the minimum time stamp at this site subtracted from the maximum time stamp at the site

```
data %>%
  group_by(Individual) %>%
  arrange(Dates) %>%
  group_by(Individual, Site) %>%   
  summarise(time_spent = max(Dates) - min(Dates))

   # A tibble: 1 x 3
# Groups:   Individual [?]
  Individual Site  time_spent    
  <fct>      <fct> <time>        
1 A          40    1.472222 hours
```

This says the total time spent at this site is 1.47 hours. However, when I manually get a time difference I get an entirely different value.

```
maxtime<-("2018-04-09 17:41:17")
mintime<-("2018-04-09 16:59:03")

difftime(maxtime, mintime, units="hours")
# Time difference of 0.7038889 hours
```

The actual time at site 40 is 0.70 hours. I'm not quite sure what summarise is referencing, or why extra time is being added.

EDIT 2: Okay, this looks like a units issue! Here is more reproducible data:

```
Dates<-as.POSIXct(c("2018-04-09 16:43:44","2018-03-20 11:52:25", "2018-04-09 16:59:03",
                    "2018-04-09 18:27:23",
                    "2018-04-09 17:01:20",
                    "2018-04-09 17:41:17"))
Individual<-c("A","A","A","A", "A","A")
Site<-c("38","38", "40","40","40", "40")

data<-data.frame(Dates, Individual, Site)
                Dates Individual Site
1 2018-04-09 16:43:44          A   38
2 2018-03-20 11:52:25          A   38
3 2018-04-09 16:59:03          A   40
4 2018-04-09 18:27:23          A   40
5 2018-04-09 17:01:20          A   40
6 2018-04-09 17:41:17          A   40

data %>%
  group_by(Individual) %>%
  arrange(Dates) %>%
  group_by(Individual, Site) %>%   
  summarise(time_spent = max(Dates) - min(Dates))
# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   Individual [?]
  Individual Site  time_spent    
  <fct>      <fct> <time>        
1 A          38    20.202303 days
2 A          40     1.472222 days
```

Here, it says time spent at site 40 is 1.47 days, but this should be hours! According to manually finding time differences below:

```
maxtime<-("2018-04-09 18:27:23")
mintime<-("2018-04-09 16:59:03")

difftime(maxtime, mintime, units="hours")
# Time difference of 1.472222 hours
```

How can I correct this units issue? Instead of displaying hours intermixed with days, I would like R to calculate the time for all sites in days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITED SOLUTION: after some trial and error this is what ended up working. This  uses a function from `data.table` so you'll need to have that installed.

**Step 1**: create a unique ID for all site observations (by site), ordered by `Date`

```
    data %>%
      arrange(Individuals, Dates) %>%
      mutate(rle_id = data.table::rleid(Sites))

                 Dates Individuals Sites rle_id
1  2018-03-20 11:52:25           A    38      1
2  2018-04-09 16:43:44           A    38      1
3  2018-04-09 16:59:03           A    40      2
4  2018-04-09 17:01:20           A    40      2
5  2018-04-09 17:41:17           A    40      2
6  2018-04-09 18:27:23           A    40      2
7  2018-03-20 11:52:25           B     4      3
8  2018-03-20 12:05:25           B     4      3
9  2018-03-20 12:10:40           B     6      4
10 2018-03-20 12:12:51           B     6      4
11 2018-03-21 02:01:23           B     7      5
12 2018-03-21 02:45:01           B     7      5
13 2018-03-21 03:30:00           B     4      6
14 2018-03-21 03:45:00           B     4      6
15 2018-03-21 05:00:00           B     6      7
16 2018-03-21 05:45:00           B     6      7
17 2018-03-22 12:01:44           B     4      8
```

You could get the relid using something in base like what I have pasted below, but it is probably much slower (and harder to understand)

```
data <- data[order(data$Dates),]
rle_lengths <- rle(data$Sites)$lengths
unlist(Map(rep, 1:length(rle_lengths), rle_lengths))
[1] 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6 7 8 9 9 9 9
```

vs.

```
data.table::rleid(data$Sites)
[1] 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6 7 8 9 9 9 9
```

**Step 2**: get the time for individual A and B at each site. If we did not specify the units in difftime, it will do the calculation on individual units and display a common unit. E.g., 1.5 hours becomes 1.5 days if there is a someone there for several days.

```
data %>%
  arrange(Individuals, Dates) %>%
  mutate(rle_id = data.table::rleid(Sites)) %>%
  group_by(Individuals, rle_id, Sites) %>%
  summarise(time_spent = difftime(max(Dates), min(Dates), units = "days"))

# A tibble: 8 x 4
# Groups:   Individuals, rle_id [8]
  Individuals rle_id Sites time_spent       
  <fct>        <int> <dbl> <time>           
1 A                1    38 20.202303241 days
2 A                2    40  0.061342593 days
3 B                3     4  0.009027778 days
4 B                4     6  0.001516204 days
5 B                5     7  0.030300926 days
6 B                6     4  0.010416667 days
7 B                7     6  0.031250000 days
8 B                8     4  0.000000000 days
```

**Step 3 (full solution)**: collapse across sites

```
data %>%
  arrange(Individuals, Dates) %>%
  mutate(rle_id = data.table::rleid(Sites)) %>%
  group_by(Individuals, rle_id, Sites) %>%
  summarise(time_spent = difftime(max(Dates), min(Dates), units = "days")) %>%
  group_by(Individuals, Sites) %>%
  summarise(time_spent_new = sum(time_spent))

# A tibble: 5 x 3
# Groups:   Individuals [2]
  Individuals Sites time_spent_new  
  <fct>       <dbl> <time>          
1 A              38 20.20230324 days
2 A              40  0.06134259 days
3 B               4  0.01944444 days
4 B               6  0.03276620 days
5 B               7  0.03030093 days
```

**Data**

```
Date <-as.POSIXct(c("2018-04-09 16:43:44","2018-03-20 11:52:25", "2018-04-09 16:59:03",
                    "2018-04-09 18:27:23","2018-04-09 17:01:20", "2018-04-09 17:41:17",
                    '2018-03-20 11:52:25', '2018-03-22 12:01:44', '2018-03-20 12:05:25', 
                    '2018-03-20 12:10:40', '2018-03-20 12:12:51 ', '2018-03-21 2:01:23', 
                    '2018-03-21 2:45:01', '2018-03-21 3:30:00', '2018-03-21 3:45:00', 
                    '2018-03-21 5:00:00', '2018-03-21 5:45:00'))
Individual<-c(rep("A", 6), rep("B", 11))
Site<-c(38, 38, 40, 40, 40, 40, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 7, 7, 4, 4, 6, 6)

data<-data.frame(Dates = Date, Individuals = Individual, Sites = Site)
```

Comment: I do have visits that span multiple days, but are in the same year. Some of my individuals stay on certain sites for up to 80 days, then visit some sites for as little as a single day. What would be the best way to tackle that?

Comment: Hmm, will you ever have more than two entries per day for an individual and a site? Actually, could you explain a little more on what the time stamps are--is it arrival / departure times?

Comment: Okay, the time stamp is the date/time of an individuals position at site X. I have many positions per day, sometimes every few minutes moving around the site. Does this help?

Comment: Definitely helped, I just posted an edit. Hopefully it solves the problem. Let me know if it doesn't!! Also, the steps just add lines to the pipe, fyi. I just thought it would help to break down what the pipes were doing.

Comment: Thank you for the edit! I have gone through the code, and it makes sense. However I am still getting incorrect time. The summarize portion of the code is adding extra days for sequential sites. IE, the time at the first site is correct, but the time at the second and third site for my first individual is incorrect. I have manually calculated the times at each site for my first individual, and for some reason the code line  summarise(time_spent = max(Date) - min(Date)) is giving me incorrect times. It is adding 1.442894 days and 3.980567 days for time spent at my second and third site

Comment: It does this even when I subset data to only include one individual. So I will have like 3 time slots at one site, and the summarise function is still giving an incorrect time

Comment: That's odd. Can you upload provide a sample dataset that will reproduce the issue (just add an edit)? I would have a hard time troubleshooting the problem without it. Also, is the current output for the sample data what you would expect it to be?

Comment: Looks like it is doing what is says it is (e.g., taking the `max` minus the `min`), any reason you are not using `18:27:23`? On the sample data try this: `sort(data$Dates)` to see the dates from oldest to newest. If you do want to omit the `18:27:23` we can figure out a way to do that if there is a clear condition for exclusion!

Comment: Okay this looks like a units issue! I have updated the post to include reproducible units error.

Comment: Ahh, should have been using `difftime`. Change the first `summarise` line to this: `summarise(time_spent = difftime(max(Date), min(Date), units = "days"))`. Also, do not forget to use the updated code with the `rle_id` column (i.e., step 2 of the edit). Let me know if this does not work! If it does work I will clean up / update my answer so it is easier to read.

Comment: Glad it worked!! I updated the answer so it is a little easier to read.